# JSch Latest version

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, java-security

Which is latest stable version of [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) as of today? Official website shows `jsch-0.1.53.jar` in download section.

I need integrate latest stable version of JSch version in our product.

But change log has no information about jsch-0.1.53
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ChangeLog

> ChangeLog of JSch
>    ====================================================================
>   Last modified: Fri Jun  5 03:22:57 UTC 2015
>
> **Changes since version 0.1.52:**
>   - bugfix: the rekey initiated by the remote may crash the session.
>   - change: Logjam: use ecdh-sha2-nistp* if available,
>             ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,

Comment: Some lazy developer didn't add the changes to the changelog. Nevertheless I wouldn't ignore the newer version.

Comment: Latest Version is 0.1.55

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section *"Changes **since** version 0.1.52"* actually describes, what is new in JSch 0.1.53.

Definitely use the JSch 0.1.53.

Answer (score 0):

Source code of the last revision of JSch library, **0.1.54** is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/is/jsch), and binary *Jar* of the same release is available at [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar/0.1.54/), both tested and working fine together, leastwise for me.

Comment: Official or not, both of the above accounts belongs to the main contributor/author of the library, "ymnk" therefore I wonder if such an attribute matters or not.

Comment: Latest version is 0.1.55

Answer (score 0):

While the original implementation is probably unmaintained (latest version 0.1.55 from somewhere in 2018), there is [a fork that's active on Github](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch) (latest version 0.1.61 from 2020-10-28). I recommend having at look at that.